# How to create an Intelligent Agent

Tags: vb.net, project, agent

I am currently doing my Honours in Computer Science and taking Artificial Intelligence as a subject. As part of completing the subject I have to develop my own basic intelligent agent.

I have yet to rap my head around what I actually have to do for this project. I am not the most technically gifted programmer and I have no idea of what to do or where to start

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to where to start learning how to develop an Intelligent Agent as well as any possible idea's of what to actually do for a project?

Any VB.net references would be appreciated as well.(I know it's not the best language to develop an IA with, but due to my time constraints this is the programming language I 'feel' most comfortable with)

Thanx in advance

Comment: There should probably be more technical requirements for the project than that, as an intelligent agent can be any number of things... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_agent RE: the other classes of artificial agents section.  Lucky for you, though, the actual programming involved does not need to be very complex, it's more mathematical in most cases.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Unfortunately they didn't provide us with more technical requirements or even how wide/deep the scope of the project should be.The only requirements that they do have is that the agent should be structures in nature, but it can be pretty much anything.Thanx for the help!

Comment: You could also take a look into Finite State Machines http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine The concept of a FSM might help you better understand an Intelligent Agent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on how you define an *agents*. For instance a *multi-agent simulation* (e.g., real time systems with parallel individuals) is inherently different from *agent-based modeling* (usually a simulation following the discrete time, discrete event paradigms).

From your comments, I think the latter is what you are searching for. In computer science, we have quite a lot of things written already, see [the list of available ABM simulation platforms/environments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_agent-based_modeling_software) yourself.

I would recommend using [Repast](http://repast.sourceforge.net/) (one of the most popular environments, its previous versions also supported VisualBasic what you were searching for), or either [NetLogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/) or [Fables](http://fables.aitia.ai) (they are both domain-specific languages to do ABM).

To get an overview about ABM, [here is a tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/cscs-repast-demos/wiki/StupidModel) I wrote about a widely known toy model.

Answer (score -1):

You could use ChatGPT or Gemini API as an "engine" for your AI agent.

Depending on what your agent was supposed to do, you can control and limit the knowledge basis as a conteiner to avoi allucinations.

You can see a customer service agent (ChatGPT based) in action at:
https://anticlick.com.br